# What is the smartest way to get the rest of a pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a `pandas.DataFrame` `df`.

```
| Foo | Bar |
|-----|-----|
|   0 | A   |
|   1 | B   |
|   2 | C   |
|   3 | D   |
|   4 | E   |
```

I selected some rows and defined a new dataframe, by `df1 = df.iloc[[1,3],:]`.

```
| Foo | Bar |
|-----|-----|
|   1 | B   |
|   3 | D   |
```

What is the best way to get the rest of `df`, like the following.

```
| Foo | Bar |
|-----|-----|
|   0 | A   |
|   2 | C   |
|   4 | E   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to take a dataframe, select some rows from it and store those in a variable `df2`, and then select rows in `df` that are not in `df2`.

If that's the case, you can do `df[~df.isin(df2)].dropna()`.

- `df[ x ]` subsets the dataframe `df` based on the condition x
- `~df.isin(df2)` is the negation of `df.isin(df2)`, which evaluates to True for rows of `df` belonging to `df2`.
- `.dropna()` drops rows with a `NaN` value. In this case the rows we don't want were coerced to `NaN` in the filtering expression above, so we get rid of those.

Answer (score 3):

Fast set-based diffing.

```
df2 = df.loc[df.index.difference(df1.index)]
df2

   Foo Bar
0    0   A
2    2   C
4    4   E
```

Works as long as your `index` values are unique.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `Foo` can be treated as a unique index.

First select `Foo` values from `df1`:

```
idx = df1['Foo'].values
```

Then filter your original dataframe:

```
df2 = df[~df['Foo'].isin(idx)]
```